# Applied Error logging in PHP, pages are still blank

Tags: php

Working on a host for a client. Site is hosted by DreamHost. The index.php file is fully functional, however any pages linked to from the front page appear as blank. I couldn't find anything in the logs that were available, so some searching turned up the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

I placed that inside the top of the php code on all applicable pages, but alas no errors are showing up, and the pages are still completely blank. I'm more of a security guy than a developer, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Also the servers php.ini file has display_errors = 1 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have [@-operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) or [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) in your code. If yes, output some string to know where your script ends or use the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-log.php)-function:

```
error_log("Oh no, file: ".__FILE__." on line ".__LINE__, 1, "operator@example.com");
```

Include the following error handler in your code an try it again:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline )
{
  if (error_reporting() === 0)
  {
    return;
  }

  throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Comment: I applied both of these snippets of code, still coming up with a blank page.

Comment: perhaps if I included the code in question you could point me in the right direction? I didn't write any of this code I just ended up as the poor soul trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `error_log()` function before/after each block (if/else, for/foreach or while, function or $this->[*]) called into index.php. And continue into class file php recalled from index.php, so you could find point where system failed. Sometime, php system prints nothing error log until  you print (with `error_log()`, `print_r()` or `echo`) something near the problem.

**EDIT**

You could install php5-xdebug and/or run your index.php by command line with:

```
 php index.php
```

It will be very simple discover php error system and where system fails.

Comment: I jumped into a console and did the php index.php and the same for all affected files, 1 or two undefined indexes....would that be causing the entire page to blank out?

Comment: It's possible. You could add an if condition about these indexes: `if ( !isset( $these[$indexes] ) ) $these[$indexes] = $initialize_it_like_structure;`. And/or you don't resolve, you could post  your output.

Comment: @Stev0, I'm reading another your post. If you use `codeígniter`, check permission on applications/logs or system[s]/logs directory: you could try it `777`, run `php index.php`, read */logs/log* file, check site on browser and then modify logs directory permission with owner right.

Comment: The codeigniter site was a subdomain. This site is not CodeIgniter. I'll take alook at that anyway. Unfortunately whoever my client hired to do the programming sort of screwed him. No input validation, no congruence between apps. I'm trying to get functionality restored then I can coach the guy on how to prevent himself from getting compromised.

Comment: If you don't resolve, you post your output error in your question, pastebin.com or similar website.